# Bug when submitting properties to Get-ADUser? Saving to CSV File (Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Here is a very simplified version of Powershell script I'd like to use to return ADUser properties (in a CSV) such as name, givenName, Office etc for users in a given OU.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'Get-ADUser Properties'
$msg   = 'Enter desired User properties, each seperated by a comma:'
$default = "name, office"
$propertiesSought = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title, $default)

get-aduser -filter * -properties * -searchbase $OU | select $propertiesSought | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp.csv"
```

The script prompts the user to enter the comma separated properties into an InputBox, which is then saved as variable.  On the saved CSV file, all I can see is "**Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection**" for each of the users' details i was expecting to see...

I've tried to isolate the problem as much as I can. If the text submitted is a single word such as "name" then everything is OK. If I add anything more, even without spaces, the problem comes back.

Also, when I run the script in ISE and choose not to output to a CSV file, on each line of the console all I"ll get back is a set of empty braces for each user in the OU.

Getting this fixed, would mean a lot to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried to isolate the problem as much as I can. If the text submitted is a single word such as "name" then everything is OK. If I add anything more, even without spaces, the problem comes back.

You're really close!

`Select-Object` accepts an *array* of property names or property expressions - not a single comma-separated string.

When you pass the string `"name,email,manager"` to `Select-Object`, it starts looking for a property with the literal name `name,email,manager` - as if you'd tried to access `$user."name,email,manager"`.

Split the string into individual property names and it will work:

```
# ...
$propertiesSought = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title, $default)

# Split input string
$propertiesSought = $propertiesSought -split ',\s*'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertiesSought -searchbase $OU |Select $propertiesSought |Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: Wonderful! I've done some quick tests and it looks like all is ready. :-)