# Get-ADUser (sometimes) not returning results) based on how the property value is set

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have have become handy enough in Powershell lately to write a script (with a GUI) that can quickly find expired AD accounts etc and export the data to CSV.

It prompts the user for to enter the values (e.g Name, LastLoginDate) sought and then makes an array by splitting the string (using commas) - this is then assigned to a variable and later substituted back in (when the Get-ADUser cmdlet) gets called.

However I get nothing back.

I have isolated the problem by assigning some properties by hand (and the end of the script) and all works OK.

```
$manualProps = "Name, Enabled"
$manualpropsAsArray = $manualProps -split ',\s*'
$exampleAccountStatus = {(($_.Enabled -eq $false -or $_.Enabled -eq $true ) -and ($_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -or $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true)) -and ($_.passwordexpired -eq $false -or $_.passwordexpired -eq $true)}
 
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -filter $filter -Properties $manualpropsAsArray | Where-Object $accountStatus | Select-Object $manualpropsAsArray | Sort-Object $properySortBy @sortOrder | ft
```

I can get my user-inputted properties to return data but only if I set the `-Properties` parameter to `*`

For example,
`Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -filter $filter -Properties * | Where-Object $accountStatus | Select-Object $guiPropsAsArray | Sort-Object $properySortBy @sortOrder | ft`

It takes much longer to get the data however.

I would much rather set things so that the value for `-Properties` match those of `Select-Object`. I was able to do this easily after following the advise I received over at [Bug when submitting properties to Get-ADUser? Saving to CSV File (Powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374309/bug-when-submitting-properties-to-get-aduser-saving-to-csv-file-powershell)

I"m sure it's something small I'm doing wrong and is easy to fix. Thanks.

Comment: You say "All executes nice and quickly!" with `-Properties $manualpropsAsArray`, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it seems to work just fine with values that the I typed in (at the end of the script, as a means of isolating the problem) but will not work with the array that was created (with the help of the GUI) earlier in the script. I should also state that I compared the datatype of both arrays and they match.

Comment: you're not showing us what your `$filter` variable contains. at least im not seeing it declared.

Comment: The $filter variable defaults to just "*" / wildcard if the user enters nothing in the GUI.

Comment: I personally would never use `where-object` for this type of program since it's extremely inefficient. I would create an array of possible LDAPFilter attributes and make a construction of filters with LDAP query syntax.

Comment: @WilliamLombard Can you show us how "the array that was created (with the help of the GUI) earlier in the script." is actually created? Sounds like that's the problem here

Comment: As I have just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641478/9898643), The Get-ADUser cmdlet exposes the `PasswordExpired` extended property, which is a boolean indicating if the password is expired. It is based on the `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed` attribute. However, you cannot **filter** with this property, because it is a _computed_ attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'Where-Object' statement is causing the problem. If I remove that (and its pipe) then everything is OK - I can use identical values for '-Properties' and 'Select-Object'. It's a mystery why i am having this problem when the arrays I am testing are effectively identical!! Not a dealbreaker, but I'll set the '-Properties' parameter to the wildstar. Reports will take a little longer, but life goes on.